# Why does an offset trigger a use after realloc warning with gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I am having trouble with a gcc 12.2 warning, and I was able to create a minimal example that triggers it. I know this code doesn't really make sense, it's only for demonstration purposes. It only seems to happens with -O1 optimizations and above. The following code triggers a use after realloc warning:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void *magic (int *start, int random)
{
  size_t offset = (uintptr_t)start % 16;
  int *end = (void*)((char*)start + offset);
  ptrdiff_t diff = (char*)end - (char*)start;

  // removing this if clause (and the random function parameter)
  // fixes the warning for some reason.
  if(random > 100) { 
    return NULL;
  }

  int *new_start = realloc(start, sizeof(int)*100);

  return (char *)new_start + diff;
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/r54je3dqn

What exactly is happening here, is there some undefined behavior or is this a false positive?

Comment: FWIW, 12.1 generates the same warning.  It doesn't seem to appear in GCC versions < 12.

Comment: It looks like GCC sunk the offset calculation to under the `realloc`, which it then decided to complain about. https://godbolt.org/z/fEfq6dPn3 (compare `sink1` and `pre`)

Comment: I'll also add that setting `-fno-tree-sink` makes the warning go away, and the resulting assembly code appears to be functionally equivalent. I'd report it to the GCC bug tracker as a false positive if there isn't a bug for it already (I couldn't find one).